# Issue building deb package using Docker/Windows

Tags: docker, linux, windows, builds

I am trying to create a way for our developers to be able to build deb packages from their Windows machines. We would like to reuse what we have for *nix so I've written a few batch scripts which are failing.

So we are using Ubuntu as our base image and building upon that. Below is the error I am getting when trying to build. I've removed some company details but is still clear

```
dpkg-source: info: building <package> in <package>.tar.gz
md5sum: <package>.tar.gz: Invalid argument
dpkg-source: error: md5sum <package>.tar.gz gave error exit status 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b <package> gave error exit status 1
debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

Command used to start container `docker run --rm  -v %cd%:/target debuild-%1 %*`

Commands run inside entrypoint for container

```
mk-build-deps --install --remove --tool "apt-get --no-install-recommends --yes"
eval "debuild $DOCKER_DEBUILD_OPTS -us -uc --lintian-opts --allow-root"
```

Now this all works on Linux and Mac (with the docker run command changed to bash clearly).

What are some possible reasons this is happening?

Comment: Can you check whether the volume is actually mounted?

Comment: @BruceBecker Yes the volume is mounted, I am able to have it output a single file to the local Windows file system but not all required ones.